# Lock combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

'Six generals propose locking a safe containing top secret information with a number of different locks. Each general will be given keys to certain of these locks. How many locks are required and how many keys must each general have so that, unless at least four generals are present, the safe cannot be opened?'

I suspect this question is more complicated than my interpretation of the language. To me the answer seems to be that if each general is given n keys, there must be 3n+1 locks. This is because in the 'worst-case' scenario where each has n distinct keys, 3 generals can open 3n locks.
Perhaps this is a gross simplification, but if anyone cares to comment that would be a great help!

Comment: You are missing that 1)all the locks need to be opened for the safe to open 2)some generals may have keys to the same lock.  The idea is to find a set of locks and distribution of keys that meet the requirement.  For example, if there were three generals and we wanted any two to be able to open it, we could have three locks.  Number the locks 1,2,3 and the generals 1,2,3.  Each general gets two keys, the ones that don't match his number.  You can check that any pair of generals can open all three locks, but no one general can.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to say: "If any four generals are present they together can open the safe." Because otherwise four locks and handing a single corresponding  key to each of the first four generals would satisfy the conditions of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Label the generals "A, B, C, D, E, F".
Label the locks with a subset of $\{A, B, C, D, E, F\} $.
Each general (say A) has a key to lock $L$, if the lock has a label of $A$.
Find a simple configuration which does what we want.

**Further Hint**: Consider all subsets of 3 elements. Clearly, if we have 3 generals, they cannot open all the locks. If we have 4 generals, they can open all the locks. This shows that ${6 \choose 3} = 15$ locks are sufficient. Each general has ${5 \choose 2} = 10 $ locks.

**Further further hint:** How do we show that 15 locks is sufficient? Claim: Given any 3 generals, there is a unique lock that they cannot open. Hence done.